# When I texture paint with symmetry, the painting is not centered over object origin

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image]

My model is on the right, and the texture is on the left.

When I make the mark on the right eye , the left side's mark is not centered properly.

This is my symmetry settings [image]

As you can see, the origin is in the center. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second screenshot, it looks like your origin isn't at the center of symmetry of your model. Even a slight shift can ruin symmetry tools.

This is how it tools to paint Suzanne on the perfect center of one eye, but one of them have been moved away from its origin:

[image]

To fix this:

1. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Edit Mode
2. Select bits of meshes that are in the center (maybe two symmetrical vertices at the bottom of your character's feet (here i'll do the same with Suzanne's chin))
   [image]
3. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> > Cursor To Selected
4. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> back to Object Mode
5. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Origin To 3D Cursor.
6. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset the object's location back to zero (optional)

Result:

[image]